# jQuery CSS different results for browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an app. that relies on percentages (for now, because it's the simpliest calculation) as offset positions.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/WeC9q/1/embedded/result/

The zooming works for every supported browser, while the arrow buttons that should move the car around does not.

I have identified the problem, the function `Position(element);` returns percentages only on WebKit browsers (Safari, Chrome). Other browsers use calculated pixel values.

Because movement functions rely hardly on percentages, pixel values simply doesn't cut it.

Any way to keep working with percentages, or I have to make some hardcore conversion scripts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us some more code.

Comment: For what it's worth, zooming does not work at all for me on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed zooming + movement for Firefox. Should be working with webkit too, tested with Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/WeC9q/7/

How to convert pixel to percent:

```
if(t.indexOf('px') > 0){
   t = el.position().top / el.parent().height() * 100;
}
```

No "hardcore conversion scripts" required ;)

I'm not sure why zooming with firefox didn't work. However, adding `"-moz-transform": 'scale('+ zoom +')'` to the transformations solves the problem.